# How do I select all elements inside the <body> tag for a jquery .load call?

Tags: jquery, function, load

When using `.load()` I know I can select a specific element out of the called file by using an ID, such as:

```
$('#replacediv').load('loadme.htm #loaddiv');
```

What I would like is a selector that will get everything inside of the BODY tag, without having to put a div around all that content.

```
$('#replacediv').load('loadme.htm');
```

This doesn't work, for example:

```
$('#replacediv').load('loadme.htm body');
```

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Did you try adding a callback and do an alert(responseText) to see if there really is a body tag in the response?

When you say "it doesnt work", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Your third line of code _should_ work. If I had to guess, the response does not have a `<body>` tag.

Comment: After documentation : "jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. (...) As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser."

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just give your body tag an id or class and then use that?

Comment: I tried giving the body tag an ID and it returned nothing, which suprised me.

I'm pretty sure I saw a post somewhere that showed a selector syntax for designating all the markup inside the body tag. I just can't find it. 

The problem I'm trying to solve is not getting the header information (like stylesheets) all returned with the body tag.  This actually duplicates that all in my resulting html.

Comment: How about using this after the body tag to wrap it in the div. <div class="body">...

Comment: You are loading the HTML into an existing document that already has a body tag. A document can only have one so it automatically filters anything and extracts only the HTML inside the body tag when using load.

Comment: That's not what's happening for me Jon. If you don't give a selector it flattens the head and the body and then inserts it. And this body select still doesn't work 3 years later. Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

edited: My bad, your example should work. You probably have a problem with the file path or its content.

Comment: **No.** You do not have to use IDs. ["If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded."](http://api.jquery.com/load)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should work

```
var allelement = $(document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"));
```